# mysql - linha para colunas gravity forms

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde,
Sou bem iniciante em banco de dados e programação, mas gosto de mexer quando é necessário. Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com respostas de um formulário feito no wordpress pelo gravity forms que apresenta as respostas em linha de tal modo que:

```
id  lead_id field_number    value
1   1       1               título1
2   1       2               descrição1
3   1       3               movimento1
4   1       4               status1
5   1       5               lat1
6   1       6               long1
7   1       7               nome1
8   1       8               email1
9   2       1               titulo2
10  2       2               descrição2
11  2       3               movimento2
12  2       4               status2
13  2       5               lat2
14  2       6               long2
13  2       7               nome2
14  2       8               email2
```

Sendo que lead_id é o identificador das respostas do formulário feita por cada usuário, field_number o identificador de cada pergunta em cada formulário e value é a resposta dada a cada pergunta.
Tentei já transformar as respostas para do formulário em uma nova tabela, mas quando elas fossem editadas no wordpress as respostas não seriam atualizadas. Quero minha visualização final dentro do banco de dados em uma nova tabela que será em colunas ao invés de linhas, dessa maneira:

`lead_id titulo  descricao   movimento   status  lat     long    nome    email
1       titulo1 descricao1  movimento1  status1 lat1    long1   nome1   email1
2       titulo2 descricao2  movimento2  status2 lat2    long2   nome2   email2`

Tentei diversas respostas aqui com tópicos semelhantes, mas não consigo ir muito longe, sempre dando erro. Vale lembrar que a nova tabela precisa ser dinâmica, já que a tabela do formulário irá crescer conforme as respostas. Alguma boa alma poderia ajudar?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver a partir dessa pergunta feita na plataforma em inglês.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007699/mysql-rows-to-columns/37828455#37828455

no meu caso adaptei para o seguinte código

`SELECT lead_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =1 THEN value END )  titulo,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =2 THEN value END )  descricao,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =3 THEN value END )  movimento,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =4 THEN value END )  status,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =5 THEN value END )  lat,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =6 THEN value END )  long,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =7 THEN value END )  nome,
MAX(CASE WHEN field_number =8 THEN value END )  email 
FROM or1_rg_lead_detail
GROUP BY lead_id`